# Returning to a previous menu java

Tags: java

so I'm creating this text base game where the user is playing hide and seek with the computer on a map that I have created with different places to search. The dilemma I'm currently having is how to return to a previous menu when the computer isn't in the areas to search. Here is a part of my code where I want to return to the previous menu.

```
            if(userinput1.equalsIgnoreCase(forrest)){
        System.out.println("You have come to the forrest. There are three paths. Left, Right, or Straight. Where would you like to go?");
        String userinput2 = keyboard.nextLine(); // 3 paths in a forrest

        while(!((userinput2.equalsIgnoreCase("left") || userinput2.equalsIgnoreCase("right") || 
        userinput2.equalsIgnoreCase("straight")) )){ // looping for a valid input
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again");
            userinput2 = keyboard.nextLine();   
        }

        if(userinput2.equalsIgnoreCase("left")){ // the left path in the forrest
            System.out.println("You gone left");
            System.out.println("You come across a tree house. What would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("1:Search the tree house.");
            System.out.println("2:Search the bushes around the tree house");
            System.out.println("3:Return");
            int userInputForrest1 = keyboard.nextInt();

            while(!(userInputForrest1 == 1 || userInputForrest1 == 2 || userInputForrest1 == 3)){
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again");
                System.out.println("1:Search the tree house.");
                System.out.println("2:Search the bushes around the tree house");
                System.out.println("3:Return");
                userInputForrest1 = keyboard.nextInt();

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create functions for displaying parts

e.g.

```
displayLeft()// will display options for left
displayRight()//will do the same for right etc. and navigate based on user input
```

well i don't know if it is the best way but obviously it is better than sequential coding!